# Python MQTT subscribe response/ack to publish with json

Tags: python, json, mqtt

I am trying to get an MQTT subscriber response with a message / ack to the publisher. If I use a string it works well but when I use a simple JSON I get a crash. I can not understand what I do wrong?

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+' '+str(msg.payload))
    message = json.loads(msg.payload)
    id = message['id']
    if id == 'foo123':
        mqttc.connect(broker,broker_port,60)
        time.sleep(3)  
        mqttc.publish(topic, 'ACK')
        

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect(broker, broker_port, 60)

client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message


client.loop_forever()
```

With this code I get following

```
    client.loop_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1779, in loop_forever
    rc = self.loop(timeout, max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1181, in loop
    rc = self.loop_read(max_packets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1572, in loop_read
    rc = self._packet_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2310, in _packet_read
    rc = self._packet_handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2936, in _packet_handle
    return self._handle_publish()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3216, in _handle_publish
    self._handle_on_message(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3444, in _handle_on_message
    self.on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
  File "", line 22, in on_message
    message = json.loads(msg.payload)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What I do not understand is why it works well with a string but not with JSON. Should be the same thing?

EDIT

The problem was when the ACK string came back and it expected JSON and not a string.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+' '+str(msg.payload))
    if msg.payload != b'ACK':
        try:
            message = json.loads(msg.payload)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Couldn't parse raw data: %s" % msg.payload, e)
        id = message['id']
        print(type(id))
        print(id)
        if id == 'foo123':
            time.sleep(3)  
            client.publish(topic, 'ACK')
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `msg.payload` in `str()`

e.g.

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+' '+str(msg.payload))
    message = json.loads(str(msg.payload))
    id = message['id']
    if id == 'foo123':
        client.publish(topic, 'ACK')
```

`msg.payload` is a byte array not a string, and `json.loads()` is expecting a string.

You also should **NOT** be creating a new client to publish message, just use the same one that is already connected.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately it did not work. The variable 'id' is a string and the if statement works as it should and 'ACK' is sent as it should to the publisher. It is after that that the crash comes. As I mentioned earlier, it works if I use a string instead of JSON. Can not understand it because the crash seems to come after JSON is finished.

Comment: The stack trace is definitely for the `json.loads()` which the change I mentioned will fix. I have updated the answer with a change to use the existing MQTT client object. You should not be starting a new client to publish the response.

Comment: Found the problem and added an edit with an ugly solution. Now I just have to find a better solution. Thank you! I'm a newbie. :)

Comment: you could always pass your ACK as json, with:  `client.publish(topic, json.dumps('ACK'))`